# Oracle find out number of days delayed with bind variable

Tags: sql, oracle

Table PROJECT

```
PROJECT     PJID     STARTDYA       ENDDAY         STATUS
Lakers      P01      03/01/2021     04/01/2021     SExceed
Lakers      P03      04/01/2021     05/01/2021     NonExceed
Lakers      P04      02/01/2021     03/01/2021     NonExceed
Bulls       P05      09/01/2021     10/01/2021     EExceed
Bulls       P06      07/01/2021     08/01/2021     EExceed
Heat        P07      08/01/2021     09/01/2021     SExceed
Heat        P08      05/01/2021     06/01/2021     NonExceed
```

Assume the user set the bind variable is 10/31/2021, if the status is SExceed, than calculate the days delayed by the (bind variable - STARTDYA), if the staus is EExceed, than calculate the days delayed by the (bind variable - ENDDYA). If the status is NonExceed, no need to calculate the day delay. Here is my expected output.

Expected output:

```
PROJECT      PJID      DaysDelayed
Lakers       P01       244
Bulls        P05       30
Bulls        P06       91
Heat         P07       60
```

Here are the pseudo code I currently thinking

```
Select PROJEC,  PJID, (bind variable - STARTDYA) as DaysDelayed, (bind variable - STARTDYA) as DaysDelayed
From
PROJECT
Where
STATUS = 'SExceed' or STATUS = 'EExceed'
```

May I ask how to possible to code it?

Answer (score 0):

This is achievable using `select case` and `date` functions.

```
Select PROJECT,  PJID, 
     CASE WHEN STATUS = 'SExceed' THEN
     TO_DATE('10/31/2021', 'MM/DD/YYYY') - TO_DATE(STARTDYA, 'MM/DD/YYYY')
     WHEN STATUS = 'EExceed' THEN
     TO_DATE('10/31/2021', 'MM/DD/YYYY') - TO_DATE(ENDDAY, 'MM/DD/YYYY')
     END as Days_Delayed
From
PROJECT
Where
STATUS = 'SExceed' or STATUS = 'EExceed'
```